# Intermittent right-to-left mirroring of UI and text

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm seeing intermittent right-to-left mirroring of the UI and text in my Flex 4 app, and that is a problem, because our app is English only, so we don't want rtl at all. Don't know why this is occurring.

layoutDirection property affects mirroring of the UI controls, for example buttons in HGroup being laid out left-to-right or right-to-left.
direction affects mirroring of the text controls, for example text in a TextInput or TextArea being laid out left-to-right or right-to-left.

This link is to a bug in Flex to be fixed in SDK 4.5, but our app does not have "Use Flex 3 compatibility mode" turned on:

http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-26473

This link is to a StackOverflow post on the topic, which led to the above bug link. It mentions problems can occur if the development machine locale is set to a rtl locale, but I assume that is not our case.

So does anyone have any idea why a Flex app would mirror the UI and text unexpectedly?

Answer (score 0):

My team has experienced the same problem, but we are in the case of the reported bug, as we use Flex3 compatibility mode.

The proposed workaround (adding layoutDirection: "ltr"; ) worked for us.

I guess this bug can still occur even without the compatibility mode, the layout direction is quite new and apprarently buggy.

Did the workaround solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this happen when I tried to call `initialize()` of the component myself.
I don't use flex 3 compatibility mode.

Could that be your issue?